# Password does not work in Ethereum Wallet

Tags: wallets, password, recovery

I have read the other threads on this topic where people have shared their experiences of not being able to decrypt their password on the Ethereum Wallet.

I had gone through all the steps of setting up a password on creating the Main Etherbase account and then noting it down somewhere else. Last week, I attempted to transfer some Ethers from that Etherbase account to a new account I had created on the Wallet application.

I typed in my password when prompted on the transaction window, clicked `Send Transaction`, but I got the `wrong password` alert. I know that this was the correct password. After several attempts, even using lower case and sometimes with the `_` symbol, neighbouring keys in case I had mistyped BUT no success.

I sent my wallet file to WalletRecoveryServices.com for Dave Bitcoin to decrypt. But not even he could decrypt it. What has happened here? Is it to do with the json file that the Wallet application generates? Does it mean that my Ethers are lost forever?